# How to solve functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations

I have been struggling to solve this functional equation. Could anyone suggest ways to solve it? It's this:
$$f\left(\frac{x-3}{2x+4}\right)=\frac{x+1}{3x-1}.$$
How do I solve it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Let $$\frac{x-3}{2x+4} = y.$$
Consequently, $$x-3 =y(2x+4) = 2yx+4y \implies (1-2y)x = 4y+3 \implies x = \frac{4y+3}{1-2y}.$$

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Substitute $x = \frac{4y+3}{1-2y}$ on both sides to find $f(y)$.

Comment: @McLinux: I think the issue here is how you arrived at the expression for $x$ in terms of $y$.  As currently phrased this "hint" is more appropriate for a Comment than for an Answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Answer (score 2):

let $$t=\frac{x-3}{2x+4}$$ then we get by solving for $x$: $$x=\frac{-4t-3}{2t-1}$$
can you finish?
now you must plug this $x$ in the right-hand side of the equation above and we get
$$f(t)=\frac{t+2}{7t+4}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still fail to see how the second statement (x) came to be.